# Switches and cases formatting?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

Working on this for a school assignment, and confused about how switches and cases work. I thought I finally got it to work, but I am still getting a formatting error, and I'm not sure why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartyAffiliation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            String Party = null;
            boolean running = true;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            loopParty: while(running)
            {
                System.out.println("What is your politcal party? (D for Democrat - R for Republican - I for Independent");
                Party = in.nextLine();

                switch (Party)
                {
                    case ("D"):
                        System.out.println("You get a Democratic Donkey!");
                        running=false;
                        break;
                    case ("R"):
                        System.out.println("You get a Republican Elephant!");
                        running=false;
                        break;
                    case ("I"):
                        System.out.println("You get an Independent Man!");
                        running=false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("I guess you aren't any of the three.");
                        break;       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a formatting error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at PartyAffiliation.main. I'm not sure, I don't know very much about Java.

Comment: That's a compile error because your `do` loop doesn't have a corresponding `while` condition. If you want it to loop infinitely, replace `do` with `while(true)`.

Comment: probably not wanting the `do` at all,

Comment: Thanks, looks like that did fix it. It does keep looping which I don't want, but Ill try to fix that.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `boolean` sentinel like `running`. And you can't have a raw `do` block (without a `while`, which you really don't need). Use an infinite loop, label it and then you can `break` on that label. Also, it's better (IMO) to allow mixed case input (so I would call `toUpperCase()` on the input). Like,

```
String party = null; // <-- follow Java naming conventions. Party looks like a Class.
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
loop: while (true) {
    System.out.println("What is your politcal party? (" + 
             "D for Democrat - R for Republican - I for Independent");
    party = in.nextLine();

    switch (party.toUpperCase()) {
    case "D": // <-- you don't need () around your case values
        System.out.println("You get a Democratic Donkey!");
        break loop;
    case "R":
        System.out.println("You get a Republican Elephant!");
        break loop;
    case "I":
        System.out.println("You get an Independent Man!");
        break loop;
    default:
        System.out.println("I guess you aren't any of the three.");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but would personally have `String party = in.nextLine();`
`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I assumed OP wants the variable after the loop. But yes, I agree it's best to limit the scope to the minimum necessary.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your intent correctly, perhaps you want to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Party = null;
    boolean running = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("What is your politcal party? (D for Democrat - R for Republican - I for Independent");
        Party = in.nextLine();

        switch (Party) {
            case ("D"):
                System.out.println("You get a Democratic Donkey!");
                running = false;
                break;
            case ("R"):
                System.out.println("You get a Republican Elephant!");
                running = false;
                break;
            case ("I"):
                System.out.println("You get an Independent Man!");
                running = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("I guess you aren't any of the three.");
                break;
        }
    } while (running);

}
```

`do` should come with matching `while`. You want to keep asking for input from user until they enter a valid input (i.e. D, R, or I).

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I was trying to do, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question, please click on the check mark beside the answer. This lets people know that the question was answered, and gives credit to the person who wrote it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!